# Como montar uma tabela com Numero da Semana Atual mais as próximas 15 Semanas

Tags: php, html, table

Como posso montar uma tabela (HTML + PHP) usando o número da semana atual e as próximas 15 Semanas, por exemplo:

```
Semana Atual é 29 então teremos 29+15 = 44
```

A tabela ira exibir as informações obtidas do banco de dados da semana 29 até a semana 44

segue exemplo de como os dados podem ser obtidos
[image: Informações]

**Complemento**: Uma outra dificuldade seria quando estivermos próximo do final de ano, onde está tabela ira precisar exibir as informações as informações dos dois anos por exemplo: 2015/2016

```
Semana 42 + 15 = 57 (Porém o numero máximo de semanas por ano é 52)
Então teríamos 57-52 = 5 e o resultado a ser exibido seria
2015: 42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49-50-51-52
2016: 1-2-3-4-5
```

Caso não tenha como eu posso exibir somente 1 ano por vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já consegui resolver minha própria duvida, agradeço a atenção de todos.

Código utilizado como base para solucionar a duvida.

```
  // volta para segunda
  $date = new DateTime('first monday this week');
  // numero de semanas desejadas
  $semanas = 15;
  // array de queries
  $query_semanal = array();

  // enquanto tiver semanas
  while($semanas > 0) {
      // clonamos a data
      $fim = clone $date;
      // adicionamos 6 dias, para chegar no 'sabado'.
      $fim->modify('+6 day');

      // adicionando a query
      $query_semanal[] = sprintf("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendas WHERE vendas.data_venda BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' AND vendas.codproduto = produtos.codproduto) as semana_%s", $date->format('Y-m-d'), $fim->format('Y-m-d'), $date->format('W'));

      // movemos a data principal para a próxima segunda
      $date->modify('+7 day');

      // diminui o número de semanas
      $semanas--;
  }

  // montando a query final
  $query_final = sprintf('
      SELECT produtos.codproduto,
             produtos.nome,
             produtos.cor,
             %s
        FROM produtos', implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $query_semanal));

  echo '<pre>';
  echo $query_final;
```